# It is time to [snap] our fingers and clean this tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

It seems from searching questions in 2014 that SO needs a new tag for Berkeley's 2014 Snap! visual block programming language. https://snap.berkeley.edu/

Several of these questions are tagged [snap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap) or [snap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap-framework), which the system regards as synonyms.

'snap' seems to be used less than 'snap-framework'?

<s>Do you agree that the natural tag for Snap! is 'snap'?</s>

Should we request the mods / admins to break the link between the synonyms? (and then fix up the tags by hand.)

**Update 2019**

By 2019, the [snap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap-framework) tag was *also* being misused for questions about other unrelated software called Snap. For example

1. [snap.svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap.svg) a JavaScript Library
2. Stanford's graph analysis library https://snap.stanford.edu/index.html
3. Canonical's Linux package format https://docs.snapcraft.io/getting-started/3876

Comment: Fix the tags by hand, hm? Are there many such questions?

Comment: @MrLister I don't think there are many questions tagged 'snap' that would have to move. I am not sure of an efficient way to find out. I could imagine automatically retagging all questions with the 'snap' tag that mention 'Haskell', but it may be easier to do manually.

Comment: Hmm, never heard of Haskell being referred to as a "drag-and-drop language" :)  I'd say the natural tag for an obscure product like this is [berkeley-snap].

Comment: [snap-framework] is in a mess of sorts.There's around [72 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsnap-framework%5D+-%5Bhaskell%5D+-%5Bcabal%5D+is%3Aq) which have to be manually retagged.  I'll try to work on this when I get time (no promises though, but some hope after 5 years)

Comment: It seems like this was tagged with [status-completed] but the [tag:snap] synonym is still in place. As such, plenty of non-haskell / non-snap-framework related questions ended up as [tag:haskell-snap-framework]

Comment: What is the best way to stop [tag:snap] being misused if we remove the synonym?  Bhargav said this when he completed the task: "I've left it with the haskell framework, as that's the one which is the most famous snap"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went through the 76 questions in the tag, that did not have the [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) tag. The [snap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap-framework) tag was not being used just for Haskell Snap or for Berkeley Snap. There were a plethora of other usages, which include:

- Snap packaging, used for linux systems, which I retagged with a pre-exiting [snap-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap-package) (x 9). (Lots of general computing questions were there, which I closed). I then found out that there was another [snapcraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snapcraft) (x 73) tag, so I merged the two tags.
- Sub Network Access Protocol, for which I created [sub-network-access-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sub-network-access-protocol)
- Stanford Network Analysis Project, for which I created [stanford-snap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-snap).
- Sentinel Application Platform, for which I created [sentinel-application-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sentinel-application-platform)
- Simple .NET Aspect-Oriented Programming, for which I just added the [aop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aop) tag.
- Social Networks Auto Poster plugin for WordPress, for which I just added the [wordpress-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin) tag here.
- Snapping objects (UI elements), there was a [snapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snapping) for these questions.
- jakiestfu's Snap-JS, used the pre-existing [snap.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap.js) tag for this.
- jtrussell's Angular-Snap-JS, used the [angular-snap.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-snap.js) tag for this.
- stereobooster's React-Snap, used the pre-existing [react-snap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-snap) tag for this.
- 1 question related to this snap https://pypi.org/project/snap, where I just removed the tag.

There were some 15 questions remaining, without the [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) tag, after the cleanup. The main issue here was that the tag was named "snap-framework", which is why users didn't know as to what snap framework it was being used for. I renamed it as [haskell-snap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-snap-framework), which should reduce most of the retags.

Comment: Cool. Nice work. What about the [tag:snap] synonym? Where should that point, if anywhere?

Comment: I've left it with the haskell framework, as that's the one which is the most famous snap.

Answer (score 2):

I like @HansPassant 's answer better than my original proposal:

> Create a new tag `berkeley-snap` and deprecate the `snap` tag. (I
>   guess there is no way to stop people using the snap tag, other than
>   mentioning the alternatives in the tag wiki excerpt.)

It sounds like both Snap framework (Haskell) and Snap language (UC Berkeley) are both quite obscure to the current SO community.

Comment: 1. No-one has created the [berkeley-snap] tag. 2. No-one has broken the link between the synonyms. 3. Now questions about unrelated libraries [snap.svg] (Javascript) and Stanford SNAP are mistakenly getting this tag.  4. So I'll unaccept this answer