# 'loopback' tag being hijacked for loopbackjs

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I'm seeing the [loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopback) tag being increasingly used for people who actually mean [loopbackjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopbackjs), after somebody released a poorly named ORM wrapper for node.js named Loopback.

Is there any reasonable way to deal with this beyond tediously fixing them all?

I'm thinking of something like replacing [loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopback) with [loopback-ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopback-ip) so that 'loopback' is no longer a valid tag and people have to actually look at what they're entering.

Or should the tag's new mixed meaning simply be accepted, with a tag wiki edit to reflect it?

Comment: Only 159 questions tagged `loopback`, and 8 questions tagged `loopback + javascript`. 12 questions tagged `loopback + loopbackjs` (that last one really gets me).

Comment: @gunr2171 Also [tag:loopback] + [tag:nodejs] or [tag:strongloop]

Comment: @gunr2171 In fact I'd say almost all are Javacript related. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopback+angularjs .

Comment: For the record, I have no expertise in this area, I only wanted to throw out some neutral stats. So I can't judge or comment on anything here.

Comment: A number of the questions that were tagged loopback would benefit from a tag such as audio-loopback, but there is no such tag at the moment.

Comment: This question is similar to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272307/how-to-break-the-link-between-tag-synonyms

Comment: [Tag wiki edit attempting to change the tag's purpose to the node library](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16186127)

Comment: And [another](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16186126). Bleah, also plagiarized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not good if a tag is being used for two completely unrelated things.

Most of the time it usually means that the tag is too general like [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) for example.

However, in this case the [loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopback) is a useful tag and is being incorrectly applied.

You have identified the only course of action - edit the questions using the tag incorrectly.

You can also edit the tag wiki to make it clearer that the tag is about the use in networking and not the ORM wrapper - but that won't stop people misusing the tag as they're clearly not reading the current tag wiki anyway.

Comment: Ugh. Worth a try. I thought renaming 'loopback' to 'loopback-tcp' or something would help.

Comment: @CraigRinger: That would only contain a fraction of the tags current scope though.

Comment: Too much for me to go though and edit. Almost all uses of the [tag:loopback] tag appear to be JavaScript related when you look for [tag:angularjs] alongside. I fixed the [tag:loopback] + [tag:nodejs] ones then discovered the rest...

Comment: @CraigRinger: Retagged the last 20 or so. Quite a lot of them were in dire need of a javascript-tag...

Comment: @CraigRinger What does TCP have to do with an IP loopback?  Nothing.

Comment: @Brad In fairness I did write `loopback-ip` in the original question. Yes, I understand why `loopback-tcp` isn't correct. Though if you want to get pedantic, `loopback-interface` would be more appropriate, as it isn't necessarily even IP.

Comment: I just realized now we have a lot more of these popping up.