# More loopbackjs questions in the loopback tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request, clean-up

See this question from 2014: ['loopback' tag being hijacked for loopbackjs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272479/loopback-tag-being-hijacked-for-loopbackjs)

10 months ago the [loopback4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopback4) tag was created for questions specifically about version 4 of LoopbackJS. The tag usage guidance incorrectly stated that generic Loopback questions should use [loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopback).

- There are currently 1194 questions tagged [loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopback).
- There are currently 67 questions tagged with both [loopback4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopback4) and [loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopback) instead of [loopbackjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopbackjs).
- There's 327 using both [loopbackjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopbackjs) and [loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopback) (some of which use all three).
- At least a few using just [loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopback) appear to actually be about [loopbackjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopbackjs).

I'm requesting the following:

- The usage guidance for [loopback4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopback4) be changed so that it references [loopbackjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopbackjs). (Completed: I suggested an edit that has been approved.)
- [loopback4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopback4) be renamed to [loopbackjs4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopbackjs4) for consistency.
- The incorrectly tagged questions be edited.

(I do not know if the loopback tag needs burning; we probably need feedback from some folks using that tag correctly.)

Given that there are well over 300 questions that would need to be edited, I'm seeking community approval (and assistance).

Comment: Does [loopback] need burnination?

Comment: What is Loopback4? Is that the same thing as LoopbackJS?

Comment: @SamuelLiew I don't know if that tag needs burning. There are questions using it that aren't about loopbackjs.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, it's just version 4 of LoopbackJS.

Comment: I think this needs a cleanup of the incorrectly tagged questions, not a burn. There are plenty of old loopback questions that predate loopbackjs that properly use it (along with some of the newer ones, of course).

Comment: I think we should rename [loopback] to [network-loopback], [loopback4] to [loopbackjs4], and [loopbackjs] to [common-word-but-in-js] ;-).