# Request to rename [haskell-snap-framework] to [snap-framework]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

As per [How to rename a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag), this is a request to remove redundancy from the [haskell-snap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-snap-framework) tag to the available [snap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap-framework) since most library tags do away with the primary language used unless there is a collision.

It already has a [snap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap) [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell-snap-framework/synonyms) so dropping "haskell-" from the main tag shouldn't be disruptive.

EDIT: Seems like this tag was previously [snap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap-framework) but was renamed to [haskell-snap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-snap-framework) due to several mistagging of questions as per [this previous retag request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385480/539209).

As per the synonym statistics, 320 [snap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap) questions have been retagged with [haskell-snap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-snap-framework) however there are currently 220 questions with such a tag. As such, the related discussion on removing the [snap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap) synonym is pending and this discussion on renaming [haskell-snap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-snap-framework) for [snap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap-framework) can take place without undoing or countering that previous effort/discussion.

And on inspecting the recently tagged [haskell-snap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-snap-framework) questions there are still *plenty* of misstagged questions that are not related to any sort of [snap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap-framework).

Comment: Deleted the [tag:snap] synonym.

Answer (score 6):

Since the [previous discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272307/it-is-time-to-snap-our-fingers-and-clean-this-tag) shows that the tag intentionally uses the longer name to avoid confusion and conflicts, renaming it back would be counterproductive.

So the tag should not be renamed.

Comment: However, I would counter-argue that the creation of the other tags (like snap-package, snapcraft, etc) would make the ambiguity clear and all those other snap tags aren't frameworks.

Comment: Besides, the issue on that discussion has to do with the [snap] synonym more than the [snap-framework] tag which wasn't removed!

It seems like the synonym would still need removal since [snap] is ambiguos.